# Tiva C TM4C123GXL digital outputs problem

Tags: c, arm, embedded, cortex-m, rtos

I didn't find the same problem like my anywhere, but I hope someone have any advices what happenin with my uC.
Digital outputs are very "sensitive / delicate". Namely, I have connected PC4-PC7 outputs to the L298N driver, and randomly, automaticaly the outputs shutting off.
I wrote a test program to run two motors in parallel eg. 2s forward, 2s stop, 2s reverse. The single motor stops randomly, but in the next sequence starts again, but in the next step again other motor stop. When I took tiva into my hand these motoros works proper. I have no idea what's happening. During this situation i measured voltage on the wrong working pin and there was ~1V, not 3.3V.
Are there any noises ?
And in parallel i have connected HD44780 and also there the trashes are appearing.
It doesn't mind if I supply Tiva with USB port, or I use +5V from the L298N board on tiva VBUS pin.
Can anyone please give me any tip what can i check next ?

Changing software, different supply, different board position, checking connections

Comment: 1V instead of 3.3V on digital output from Tiva?

Comment: do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not :(
Yes 1V is there, when something crashes. But maybe it is 1V  inducted from L298N, not Tiva DO.

Comment: Since the LCD gets garbled is it possible the microcontroller restarted due to a power glitch? (If this is happening, putting a big capacitor in parallel with the microcontroller's power rails would reduce or eliminiate it. You could try it and see if it changes anything)

Comment: No, uC still working because, after reset i have some other "hello world" information displaying for some seconds and in this situation it is not happening. And the second motor is still working. The Sequence keep going. Only some DOs are getting disabled.

Comment: Since this is more of an electronics question, is it okay if I ask the moderator to move this question to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ ? You might have to sign in to that site using the same account.

Comment: well, the automated message says I should only ask if the question is written clearly, which I don't think this is. If you want to edit the question to make it easier to read and understand, such as describing what you did and what happened, then after that, you can flag your own question for moderator attention. Just select "flag" and then "other" and write a short note asking it to be moved to the electronics site. But they will only do it if it's a good question.

Comment: without a scope not sure how you expect to do this kind of work.  they are super cheap now for a good one.  you have provided no minimal example so this could just be a software bug.